# How to get inbox's coversation's users and its last messages in NodeJS with MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

### **MongoDb User Collection**

---

Think that you are **User 1**. In the inbox page, I want to get the conversation's last message. I may sent the last message or receive the last message from a user. The last message will be shown in inbox like this:

**Query Result Shold Be Like This**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "user2",
    "username": "user2",
    "lastMessage": "3"
  },
  {
    "_id": "user3",
    "username": "user3",
    "lastMessage": "2"
  }
]
```

**User 1 Document on MongoDb**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("user1"),
    "username" : "user1",
    "inbox" : [ 
        {
            "from" : {
                "user" : {
                    "id" : ObjectId("user2")
                }
            },
            "message" : "1",
            "received_at" : ISODate("2019-04-27")
        },
        {
            "from" : {
                "user" : {
                    "id" : ObjectId("user3")
                }
            },
            "message" : "2",
            "received_at" : ISODate("2019-05-1")
        }
    ]
}
```

**User 2 Document on MongoDb**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("user2"),
    "username" : "user2",
    "inbox" : [ 
        {
            "from" : {
                "user" : {
                    "id" : ObjectId("user1")
                }
            },
            "message" : "3",
            "received_at" : ISODate("2019-04-29")
        }
    ]
}
```

**User 3 Document on MongoDb**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("user3"),
    "username" : "user3",
    "inbox" : [ 
        {
            "from" : {
                "user" : {
                    "id" : ObjectId("user1")
                }
            },
            "message" : "4",
            "received_at" : ISODate("2019-04-30")
        }
    ]
}
```

---

What query I have to use for this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$inbox"
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            participants: [ "$_id", "$inbox.from.user.id" ]
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { participants: "user1" }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            participants: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$participants",
                    cond: {
                        $ne: [ "$$this", "user1" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$participants"
    },
    {
        $sort: { "inbox.received_at": -1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$participants",
            lastMessage: { $first: "$inbox.message" }
        }
    }
])
```

The challenge here is that you need to analyse an array which might contain for instance [user1, user2] or [user2, user1] and both should be considered as the same grouping key.

To do that you can introduce `participants` array in order to filter out all the messages that do not belong to `user1` and then remove `user1` from that array (using [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html)) so that you can group by second user.

The point is that you run [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to get single document per message and then [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) them so that you can run [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) with [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/index.html) to get the most recent one

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7LK7skqummX)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, there is problem. Because, last messages have to be 3 and 2. In your answer, they are 3 and 4. Missing point is 'User1' sent the last message to 'User3' in their conversation.

Comment: @ŞerefCanMuştu I must have missed that, apologies, modified my answer and Mongo Playground

Comment: Thank you so so so much. You saved my life by answering this question. @mickl

Comment: Sorry to comment you again but need one more favor from you. Is there a way to get username too in the result ? I edited my question how necessary to get the result. I've tried to make it but I'm not professional at MongoDb, therefore I couldn't.

Comment: @ŞerefCanMuştu well you can add `{ $first: "$username" }` but this will fail for the cases where last message is stored under `user1` id. Two ways: 1. modify your data model and embed `username` to every message 2.run second query using  $in operator to get usernames by id